# Convert string to SHA1 and to base64

Tags: php

I am having problem with converting the string, lets say: "TestPassword" to SHA1 and to base64.

Generally according to that site: 
http://www.online-convert.com/result/1f76972748a7d186198171e9a11e9493

I should be given the results below for the above password:

```
hex: 6250625b226df62870ae23af8d3fac0760d71588
HEX: 6250625B226DF62870AE23AF8D3FAC0760D71588
h:e:x: 62:50:62:5b:22:6d:f6:28:70:ae:23:af:8d:3f:ac:07:60:d7:15:88
base64: YlBiWyJt9ihwriOvjT+sB2DXFYg=  <-- That is what I would like to achieve ...
```

There is no problem with converting string to SHA1 but i don't know how to convert it again to base64 as there is a need to treat every two characters as a hex byte and then pass it to base64 function.

Could someone please throw light on it or paste code snippet how to do it?

Thank You!

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to convert SHA1 to base64 to obtain the above result

Comment: Bear in mind that SHA1 is no longer recommended for password hashing. Use `password_hash` instead if you can.

Comment: @John you could probably have avoided downvotes by actually including the code you already had.

Comment: I know but in this particular situation I was unable to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Base64 encoding should be performed on the raw binary version of the SHA1 digest, not the hex encoding of it.

You can get that raw version by passing `true` for the `$raw_output` parameter of the `sha1()` function:

```
$base64 = base64_encode(sha1("TestPassword", true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is a late response but I achieved that exact value by using the raw md5 and then converting it to base64:

```
$base64 = base64_encode(hash("md5", "myPassword", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please run this command in terminal,

```
echo 6250625B226DF62870AE23AF8D3FAC0760D71588 | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
```